# $_POST in php 5.3.5 does not work

Tags: php

I'm working on a page in PHP 5.3.5, and it seems that `$_POST` doesn't contain the data submitted from my form.

This is the HTML file :

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the PHP file:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the form values are not passed, so I get output like this:

```
Welcome !
You are years old.
```

Instead of this:

```
Welcome John!
You are 28 years old.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have POSTed to it? Can you see the POST body with the info in the headers?

Comment: if you view source on the welcome.php, do you see the php or just blanks?

Comment: Maybe a small thing like a spelling of your welcome.php file, perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

Try `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` to see what's really in there. There's no way $_POST is broken - it's gonna be something else. Possibly a server setting could be disabling $_POST.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you have magic_quotes_gpc turned on. You should turn it off:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.3 is moving away from using global, pre-set variables, like $_POST, to avoid vulnerabilities.

The issue, as I understand it, is that programmers who have never had to use $_POST or $_GET might treat it as any other variable and open themselves up to security threats.

I haven't discovered the "proper" way to retrieve $_POST data yet, but the method I've using seems fairly sanitary.

```
<?php parse_url(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST);
```

This transfers the parsed HTTP POST string to the $_POST variables

Answer (score 2):

Have you check your php.ini ?
I broken my post method once that I set `post_max_size` the same with `upload_max_filesize`.

I think that `post_max_size` must less than `upload_max_filesize`.
Tested with PHP 5.3.3 in RHEL 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Is your HTML form *method* se to to **POST**?

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<fieldset><legend>your data</legend>
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="id_name" />
<input type="text" name="txtage" id="id_age" />
</fieldset>
<button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not POSTed, or something is clobbering `$_POST`.

If you have no mention of `$_POST` in your code before trying to access them, then you haven't POSTed to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Here it worked, but in PHP 5.3.1. Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>form</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="process.php">
<fieldset><legend>your data</legend>
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="id_name" />
<input type="text" name="txtage" id="id_age" />
</fieldset>
<button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>


<?php
if(isset($_POST["txtname"]))
    $txtname = $_POST["txtname"];
else
    unset($txtname);
if(isset($_POST["txtage"]))
    $txtage = $_POST["txtage"];
else
    unset($txtname);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>form</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<p>Welcome <?=$txtname; ?>!<br />
You are <?=$txtage; ?> years old.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use capitals in POST:

```
<form action="file.php" method="POST">
```

Instead of:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.I used windows notepad for editing .php file and accidentally saved the file in Unicode encoding and that was creating the problem. Then I saved it in the UTF-8 encoding, and it worked like a charm. Hope this might help.