# PHP $_POST not working?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have the simplest form possible and all I want to do is echo whatever is written in text box.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $test = $_POST['firstname'];
  echo $test;
}
```

The problem is it's not working on my server (it works on another server). Does anyone has an idea what could be wrong? There are other forms on the server and are working fine.

Comment: I'd always recommend that the `action` attribute had a value...

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST)`? And come to that, `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: What version of PHP is your server running?

Comment: in action attribute you have to write like eg "test.php" or "#".try this

Comment: It's working very well in my server. What version of PHP you use?

Comment: Run `php -i` on both server. Then check the `diff`

Comment: There must be something else there other than these two snippets.

Comment: @DaveRandom if I var_dump($_POST) I _sometimes_ get a result back but otherwise it's just an empty array. Also I sometimes get the right value back and when I try again with a different string, the value stays the same as the first time - it doesn't change.

Comment: @belovah Please will you edit the question with the full code from your script?

Comment: @DaveRandom This is the full script. I have commented everything else out.

Comment: Check my answer below. If you are in a Linux environment, make sure you have Read/Write permissions to the file.

Comment: As you said it does not work on our server but works on another server, the error is in your server not code

Comment: Have you tried this : if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

Answer (score 33):

I had something similar this evening which was driving me batty. Submitting a form was giving me the values in $_REQUEST but not in $_POST.

Eventually I noticed that there were actually two requests going through on the network tab in firebug; first a POST with a 301 response, then a GET with a 200 response.

Hunting about the interwebs it sounded like most people thought this was to do with mod_rewrite causing the POST request to redirect and thus change to a GET.

In my case it wasn't mod_rewrite to blame, it was something far simpler... my URL for the POST also contained a GET query string which was starting without a trailing slash on the URL. It was this causing apache to redirect.

Spot the difference...

Bad:   http://blah.de.blah/my/path?key=value&otherkey=othervalue 
Good:  http://blah.de.blah/my/path/?key=value&otherkey=othervalue

The bottom one doesn't cause a redirect and gives me $_POST!

Comment: I had a form with `action="booking.php"`, which wasn't working. Turns out it was because my .htaccess rewrites .php addresses to remove the extension. changing `action="booking"` did the trick

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of time. In my case, my form had `action="mysite.com/somefolder` and that caused the `$_POST` to be empty. But when I changed the action to `mysite.com/somefolder/` it worked as expected. Thanks a lot

Comment: Very subtle difference, but big impact. Thanks for this! :)

Comment: Trying for a good hour, doing researches, and..... IT WAS A SLAAASH, OMG.... Thanks a lot.

Comment: LOL, I just had the same problem for an hour.  Gotta have that SLASH when using post !

Comment: I have been on this issue for more than a week. Thanks for the answer, as this answer is not in any of the other stackoverflow questions regarding the same issue, I think this should not be a duplicate question. Normally, I don't checkout the duplicate questions since its the duplicate questions :) - Cheers for the answer though

Answer (score 27):

A few thing you could do:

1. Make sure that the "action" attribute on your form leads to the correct destination.
2. Try using $_REQUEST[] instead of $_POST, see if there is any change.
3. [Optional] Try including both a 'name' and an 'id' attribute e.g.

   ```
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
   ```
4. If you are in a Linux environment, check that you have both Read/Write permissions to the file.

In addition, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854205/php-post-not-working) might also help.

EDIT:

You could also substitute

```
<code>if(isset($_POST['submit'])){</code>
```

with this:

```
<code>if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){ </code>
```

This is always the best way of checking whether or not a form has been submitted

Comment: You don't need the id.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried pretty much everything from that link. No success.

Comment: Have you tried this : if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

Comment: Plus one for jolting my brain into, "Oh, DUH!" mode. Solved my problem in a tangent way. I love SO.

Comment: #3 worked for me. Awesome!!! Thank You very much!!!! This problem was driving me nuts. Great!!! Plus 1. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much!! FOR EVERYONE USING LINUX, you have to GIVE PERMISSION to the file first

Comment: Sure, the name attribute!!

Answer (score 11):

Dump the global variable to find out what you have in the page scope:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

This will tell you the "what" and "where" regarding the data on your page.

Comment: This is the best solution. file_put_contents('./test.log', print_r($GLOBALS, true)); Gives a lovely print-out of all of the global vars and you can see where the data is arriving.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using $_POST, use $_REQUEST:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
  $test = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
  echo $test;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I also had this problem. The error was in the htaccess. If you have a rewrite rule that affects the action url, you will not able to read the POST variable.

To fix this adding, you have to add this rule to htaccess, at the beginning, to avoid to rewrite the url:

RewriteRule ^my_action.php - [PT]

Answer (score 2):

Have you check your php.ini ?
I broken my post method once that I set `post_max_size` the same with `upload_max_filesize`.

I think that `post_max_size` must less than `upload_max_filesize`.
Tested with PHP 5.3.3 in RHEL 6.0

FYI:
[$_POST in php 5.3.5 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137598/post-in-php-5-3-5-does-not-work/)
[PHP POST not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914979/php-post-not-working/)

Answer (score 1):

try doing `var_dump($_GLOBALS)`.

A potential cause could be that there is a script running before yours which unsets the global variables. Such as:

```
unset($_REQUEST);
```

or even.

```
unset($GLOBALS);
```

This could be done via the auto_prepend_file option in the php.ini configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**
 **html code**

```
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="firstname">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$firstname=isset($_POST['firstname'])?$_post['firstname']:"";
echo $firstname;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is not visible form here.

1. Check if after the submit, the script is called at all.
2. Have a look at what is submitted: `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Answer (score -2):

1. html file and php file both should reside in htdocs folder in c:\apache2 (if you use apache web server).
2. Open html file by typing http://"localhost/html_file_name.html"
3. Now enter Your data in fields.. Your code will run..

Answer (score -3):

Try get instead for test reasons

```
<form action="#?name=test" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and

```
if(isset($_GET)){
    echo $_GET['name'] . '<br>';
    echo $_GET['firstname'];
}
```

Comment: Nothing. It's like the value gets eaten by a ninja.

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: Huge security risk. Only fetch what you need.

Comment: because form has an action and you can just check for a general post.

Comment: I'm going to try just about anything right now, even if it doesn't make sense. This is starting to drive me crazy. I have another form on my website and it's working fine.

Comment: @belovah if it works on another server... thats strange, i'll update my question

Comment: @belovah do the getters work?

Comment: @Stevanicus $_GET works fine.

Comment: @belovah thats a new one on me :)

Comment: @belovah print_r($_POST) to see if anything is passed at all

Comment: @Stevanicus Here's what I did: entered a string, submitted the form and got no result. Then I browsed the web for a couple of minutes, came back to my website, entered a string ("test") and got back the same value! Then I entered another string ("12345"), submitted and the value stayed the same as before ("test"). Tried again and again, the value is still "test", whatever string I write in the text box. This is weird. >_<