# PHP POST not working

Tags: php, html, forms, post, echo

```
<?php echo $_POST['ss'];?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<input name="ss" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This code should print whatever is enter in text box name="ss" when click submit.
But its not printing. Working with method="get" but not with post, What's the problem.

Comment: What do you see when you `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: Why are you using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, when you could leave the action attribute empty if you want it to submit to itself?

Comment: Looks ok to me, what does print_r($_POST) show you?

Comment: i would guess the php_self tag is mucking things up and forcing a 302

Comment: print_r($_POST) shows empty array

Comment: Empty before or after submit the form? (or both)

Comment: Wasim, are you getting any errors?  If not, try adding `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`
This will let you see if anything else is stopping your success.

Comment: If the form is in the follow page: mywebsite.com/folder/subfolder, after submit the user go to root folder, with action="/"

Comment: @Shef why add the ID to input?

Comment: not error showing, i have action="/" its even not working, i have told you that method="get" is working for $_GET but method="post" is not working for $_POST

Comment: @Wasim have another script after/before this one?

Comment: it solve my problem by changing php_max_size = 8M in php.ini

Comment: In my case the form data was too large for PHP to handle
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133652/how-to-gracefully-handle-files-that-exceed-phps-post-max-size

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002424/php-post-not-working/17375026#

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're just refreshing the page, do:

```
action=''
```

instead of:

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"
```

Also, add this to line 2 to see what's being stored (if anything) in the $_POST array:

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

Hmm... so it's empty on submit? Try adding this to the top of your php file:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']))
{ 
  $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
}
```

Okay, now check your php.ini (normally requires sudo or root in /etc):

```
post_max_size = 8M
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

Do you have those two rules set? If so, be careful of how much memory you're allocating. Anything over 2048MB could start to give you trouble, depending on your system specs.

NOTE: If you make changes to your php.ini file and PHP is running as an apache module, you'll need to restart apache. Something along the lines of:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: What does the var_dump say? array(0)?

Comment: i did print_r($_POST), when first time page load its say Array() but when i submit, nothing in array.

Comment: Its not working answer is useless. Var dump as matthew has said and tell us the results.

Comment: Hmmm... Okay. Did you set up php yourself? Check my edited answer.

Comment: name="ss" is the key to textbox

Comment: Right. I think itachi is rightfully surprised that the $_POST array is empty.

Comment: let me check php_max_size, i have change it to upload file with more than 8MB, but what if i want to upload file with greater size. it will cause another problem

Comment: You can set the memory limit to whatever you feel comfortable with. I was just wondering if it wasn't in your php.ini at all, or if it was set to 0. :)

Comment: yes you was correct resetting php_max_size correct my problem but raise another problem, how will i upload files with more than 8MB now

Comment: @Wasim Change to more then 8MB.

Comment: What was your previous setting? You should set it to whatever you feel your server can handle! :D

Comment: i change it to 20000M for 20GB, so what's it mean, is there any limit to upload file via PHP

Comment: Well crap, that is by far the largest upload limit I have seen run on PHP. Basically, you were probably running out of memory. $_POST uploads require THREE settings to work correctly. upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, memory_limit.

Comment: i have set every thing to 20000M but i believe there should be a limited size for post

Comment: Just did some Googlin', and it looks like anything over 2GB limit can cause trouble. You may have a bigger fish to fry here! May I ask why you need a 20GB upload limit?

Answer (score 7):

It may be due to rewrite rules in the .htaccess file.Add this condition to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
```

OR add this line

```
 RewriteRule ^welcome_post.php - [PT]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ran into this problem, and your first rewrite condition fixed it perfectly! Saved me hours of pain :)

Answer (score 6):

I broken my post method once that I set `post_max_size` the same with `upload_max_filesize`.

I think that `post_max_size` must less than `upload_max_filesize`.
Tested with PHP 5.3.3 in RHEL 6.0

Comment: glad I could help :-D

Answer (score 1):

Finally ...Got it.... Firstly I have an `Article` folder in my `htdocs` file with `welcome.php` as the php file in focus and a main `HTML` file , whose contents we will be discussing about.
Here's what worked for me..
Turns out the problem was not  XAMPP or any of its related files..
The problem was this :

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
```

With this code whenever I pressed the submit button, the url redirects to here `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Article/welcome.php`, Which is not what it needs to be..It has to be a localhost link ..So I changed the value of action attribute to localhost form and now it looks like this

```
<form action="https://localhost/Article/welcome.php" method="post">
```

That did the trick..Now the submit button redirects to `https://localhost/Article/welcome.php` , this link..Which is exactly what is needed..
Remember the browser may ask you for some permission issues ..Just accept them it will run fine...
Best of luck..
P.S : This one is for Windows..Hope it will work also in Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

My friend ran into this problem today. The answer was pretty simple - basically, you have to capitalize the `POST` part of `method="POST"`

The final result should look like

```
<?php echo $_POST['ss'];?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
<input name="ss" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: this can't be it... see http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_post

Comment: Not true. [Enumerated attributes (like `method`) are case-insensitive](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#enumerated-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your web service (GET/POST etc) is acting as desired using [the Chrome Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo). Then you should check your PHP part.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine with including following into header.

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Just use this in the header while making a request and my problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

`<form action="" method="post">` method="post" is important for POST Data.

Use PHP REQUEST instead:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="mail">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
PHP:

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
  $val= $_REQUEST['mail'];
  echo $val;
}
```

Comment: "Never forget to give POST Method in html form attribute" — They didn't. You can clearly see it in the code in the question.

Comment: The method="post" will not work if the Old Cache is stored in the Web Browser. To become method="post" active, the Client must verify that POST Method is working within  the Cache Storage.

Answer (score -2):

use this instead;

```
$variable_name = $_REQUEST["ss"];
echo $variable_name;
```

Answer (score -2):

change your IDE ,i use phpstorm ,it's fantastic but when i use dreamweaver it works probably, for test you can run your page directly from wampserver localhost , i change default port of apache and i think problem is from there , if you use phpstorm or change port of apache server change your IDE.