# Unable to send data to php on select box change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

on a index.php page, inside html i have a selectbox

```html
<select name="selectLanguage" id="selectLanguage" onchange="OnlanguageChange()">
  <option value="">
    Select your Language
  </option>

  <option value="en">
    English
  </option>

  <option value="fr">
    Français
  </option>

  <option value="de">
    Deutsch
  </option>                                             

</select>
```

Wish to get the value of the select box onchange in my php code.

tried with ajax call :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#selectLanguage").change(function(){ 
    var SelectedLanguage = $(this).val(); 
    alert(SelectedLanguage);
    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      url: "index.php", 
      data: SelectedLanguage, 
      success: function(result){ 

      }
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax` require data as an object...

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  data: { language: SelectedLanguage },
  success: function(result) {

  }
});
```

In php access it as `$_POST['language']`

Comment: Have you added `data: { language: SelectedLanguage },` to your `$.ajax` function params?

Comment: Try using `filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'language' )` to avoid error when not set...

Comment: that vanished the error. but the value is not getting sent to php page

Comment: @SalilLambay what do you see in Netwroks in Chrome DevTools? Are there "form data" and "language" in this request?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын data in networks cn be seen "language : en" but not able to still get data in print filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'language' ); or $_POST['language']

Comment: @SalilLambay do you have any HTTP-redirects in this request? you can see this in Networks too. It looks like a second request.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын no... before making any select box change... i clear out  network data.. then i change the select box value and only see this one request

Comment: @SalilLambay can you show your index.php file? Do you try to get $_POST['language'] in this file, right?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын i have uploaded the file at : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ima72vfw0k3c1j/indexNew.php?dl=0 please check

Comment: @SalilLambay code is very simple and right. There is no place for error. The problem in the server ot PHP config, obviously. But I no have any recommndation, I'm sorry( You can check this thread, that is same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914979/php-post-not-working

Comment: @wpdevelopment.me could you please check the file and suggest https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ima72vfw0k3c1j/indexNew.php?dl=0

Comment: Hmm... what do you intend to do? Making ajax request to same page doesn't seem to make sense to me...

Comment: `language` var in your ajax success handler would contain entire html on the page is that what you desire...?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын finally got the solution. in usccess of ajax : these two lines --> var res = SelectedLanguage; 
     $("#result").html(res); and now a div result in php will have the value assiging it to the php vairable

Answer (score 0):

```
           var formData = {     
              //get the value of language selected
               'SelectedLanguage':$("select[name='selectLanguage'] option:selected").val(),
            };
            $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "index.php",
            //send language to index.php
            data: formData , 
            success: function(result){ 

              }
        });
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer. Only posting a bit of code doesn't provide a good answer.

Comment: Why $("select[name='selectLanguage'] option:selected")? $(this).val() is right code.

Comment: i suppose var SelectedLanguage = $(this).val();  is doing the same job that 'SelectedLanguage':$("select[name='selectLanguage'] option:selected").val() is doing... still thanks... a new way to do that

Comment: Even this gives me formdata in the networks of chrome dev tools, but in $_POST['language'] still not able to get data

Comment: to get data $_POST['SelectedLanguage'] not $_POST['language']

Comment: Still no data in  $_POST['SelectedLanguage']

Comment: add script php in another file and call it from ajax

Comment: didnt try that, but even if it does, that wont be as per requirement. Please check https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ima72vfw0k3c1j/indexNew.php?dl=0 file

Comment: update print "True";  to print "<div id='result'>True</div>"  ; 
and add var res = language.split('\n')[1];
      $("#result").html(res);  to success: function(language) {