# PHP $_POST no work

Tags: php, html, post, echo, isset

tried method get and `$_GET` it works perfect but when i try method post and `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` nothing happens =\ any help ? thanks

PHP and FORM is in SAME PAGE

HTML :

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user">Meno:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="meno admina" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="psw">Heslo:</label>
        <input type="password" id="psw" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="heslo admina" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" v>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $user = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['user']));   
    echo $user;
}
?>
```

Tried also just echo `$_POST['user'];` but nothing.

Comment: your both code in same page?

Comment: where is `action` is `<form>`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie same page yes

Comment: @PatrikHorváth check for errors then. For help check my answer

Comment: In your last input tag for the submit button you have `v>` in the end. I hope its a typing mistake.

Comment: I have tested your code but didn't get any error. Everything is ok

Comment: @AlivetoDie checked error but no ERRORS :(

Comment: @PrerakSola  thx :) but it no fixed my problem =\

Comment: @PatrikHorváth I just did some research. Don't know if it helps, but I'll list everything I saw: First of all, write `mothod="POST"` (post all in capitalized letters) - Also, do you have a .htaccess file that in some form interacts with a post method?

Comment: @Twinfriends lol this works =O

Comment: @PatrikHorváth What was it? The `POST` in capitalized letters?

Comment: @Twinfriends yup idk why with post it no work but with POST

Comment: @PatrikHorváth Great! :) I edited my answer in the case someone finds this question trough google. Btw here the source I found this information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30131766/5740849

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

For all who have the same problem, its all about this line:

`<form method="post">` - post have to be written in uppercase, like:

`<form method="POST">` - This solved the problem.

Comment: what if this guy made this code in the same page? it's not necessary to give action to page.

Comment: @AshishPatel  agree with you

Comment: @Twinfriends CODE is in same page 

<?php ?>  is after </html>

Comment: While this is true, I don't think its on the same page, since it would work perfectly if it was. (Tested)

Comment: @PatrikHorváth Well your code works perfectly on my server.

Comment: @Twinfriends in my server i use PHP 7.1 ( live server ) no works, Local server ( PHP 7.0 ) no works =\

Comment: @PatrikHorváth Thats quite weird... I just tested it on a server with 7.1 and on a older VM with PHP 5.3 ... both work..

Comment: @PatrikHorváth  check for errors.I have added error checking code in my answer.Just try that

Comment: But I have tested using post. It did not throw any error.

Comment: @NazmulHasan For me it worked with lowercase letters too. Think it has something to do with the config.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

and setup form `action` in your form tag