# My HTTP POST method isn't working in PHP, and yes, I've fixed everything in the php.ini file

Tags: php, http, post

Guys I don't know why this code isn't working. It's fairly straight forward and should work. I've tried everything, even changing the limits in the php.ini file. Please help...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<?php echo $_POST["username"];
var_dump( $_POST );
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="Okay">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does it mean "it doesnt work"? It prints nothing?

Comment: It says "Notice: Undefined index: username in D:\wamp\www\Learn1\test.php on line 4" for the code on line 4 and "array
  empty" for the code on line 5

Comment: I tested your code, it works fine, so it's not the code.... of course I get the errors you report when I load the page for the first time, but not when I submit the form, then I get the expected results. If your problem also only exists on first load, then add `if (isset($_POST)) { ...... }` around the two lines to PHP code.

Comment: Well I don't like the sound of this

Comment: I keep clicking the submit button but I just keep getting the same errors. Perhaps it's not submitting ?...
I keep getting the errors, every single time I reload

Comment: Try submitting to another page, check that it goes to the other page, if it does, it does submit. Then check `$_POST` on that other page.

Comment: It's still getting the same errors, the same ones as on the first page

Comment: Then it is time for the developer tools, press F12 on Windows (?), and see the Network tab, check the parameters. You can practice this with other forms that do work, so you know what you have to look for. This will only tell you whether the form content has been submitted, not why it doesn't end up in `$_POST`.

Comment: What am I looking for exactly ?

Comment: I'm thinking of bizarre things now. For instance, your field is called `username` and you're using an non-ssl secured url. Perhaps you've got software installed that doesn't allow this. Change the input name to something more innocent like 'testing'.

Comment: Explaining the developer tools is way beyond what I can do in a comment. Sorry.

Comment: It's still not working :(

Comment: Let's check some other answers, for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914979/php-post-not-working

Comment: Alright, sounds like a plan

Comment: To be honest, I'm out of ideas... ;-)

Comment: Hahahaha, thanks anyways dude..much appreciated :)