# PHP possible interpreter error FORM $_POST values not getting passed

Tags: php

Either I am incredibly stupid or something is wrong with my dev environment. Ive been pulling my hair out of my head for these past few days as my form `$_POST` variables are simply not getting passed.

So I have scalled it down to the most simplest of tests, just to ensure there is nothing wrong with my script, which I originally thought, which took up all my time trying to find a bug which isnt there. I tried the following and then realise it is a case where $_POST values arent getting passed

```
<form method="POST" name="login" action="test.php" id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="please enter email">
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="please enter your password">
    <button type="submit" name="submitBtn">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

**test.php**

```
var_dump($_POST);
$_POST['email'];
$_POST['password'];
```

I am hoping to get some possible solutions or advise on what I can try to further debug this.

I am using XAMPP, and PHPStorm.

`var_dump($_POST)` results in NULL{}

Comment: "email" is not a valid type attribute according to Mozilla.  type is not the name, email would be type=text - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Hi just changed it to text now, as I have tried it with text, same result

Comment: How are you accessing this in your browser? URL (such as `http://localhost/test.php`) or file (such as `/home/folder/test.php`)?

Comment: `http://localhost/FOLDER/test.php`

Comment: Sounds like something could be wrong with your dev environment, possibly PHP config issues.  What if you switch to `method="GET"` and `var_dump($_GET)`?

Comment: What page is the form on?  If it is also test.php then please post the actual code.

Comment: @cale_b gimmie a second to check

Comment: @DaveS both under root directory form is `index.php`

Comment: @cale_b interestingly. `$_GET` passes values

Comment: i don't know how you environment is set up but i came across something like this today, what happens if you try `https://localhost/FOLDER/test.php` , just making sure you're not working with `ssl`

Comment: Do you have another form in your page ? make sure they don't overlap.

Comment: So, I'm guessing there's some PHP config issue that is interfering with $_POST.  There's lots of posts on this - google "PHP $_POST not working", and one that looks like a good resource is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914979/php-post-not-working

Comment: @cale_b Yeah just the frustrating thing is I did NOT change anything and everything worked fine. I dumped it completely down and started a new project under a new root folder. There are only the index.php with post form, and the test.php which is posted aswell. UGH

Comment: Your test.php, does it have `<?php ?>` tags?  Add just a `echo "test";` to see if your PHP is configured ok to be interpreted.