# PHP $_POST is not working

Tags: php

I've recently migrated servers and found that all `$_POST` requests on my website are no longer working. The requests always successfully redirect to the 'post' page, but no data is sent and `print_r($_POST)` always turns up an empty string. I believe this issue has something to do with PHP's settings because the problem occurs over multiple pages which were working fine on the previous server (GET requests seem to still be working fine).

I created a **test.php** file in my home directory with a very simple POST form to try to rule out any variables.

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

the page always prints only an empty the array **Array ( )**

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure its something simple but google doesn't seem to have the answer :(

Comment: I've tested the script works fine.

Comment: Assuming your code is on `test.php`, and you're actually entering something in the field and then checking the array, your script does indeed work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP POST not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914979/php-post-not-working)

Comment: It know the above code should work but for some reason it doesn't. It just returns an empty array every time, no matter the input. I'm thinking the issue must be with php/server settings but Im not sure. nothing is showing up in the error logs either :(

Comment: _"The requests always successfully redirect to the 'post' page"_ <- what does this mean? There should be no _redirection_. What do you see in your browser's _Network_ console? Do you see a POST request to `test.php`? If so, what data is sent in the request payload?

Comment: *The requests always successfully redirect to the 'post' page* - Please clarify that statement. If you're redirecting, the browser will perform a GET request to the URL you're redirecting to.

Comment: you should write <?php print_r($_POST); ?> this code in your test.php write anything in your text and after that click on submit then you will definatlly see array on test.php

Answer (score 0):

I've realized the issue was in my .htaccess file. My POSTS were being stripped of their extensions and losing all the post data.

this topic [php $_POST array empty upon form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) was the most help

Comment: This does not provide an answer to your question. If you have solved the issue, you should **detail** it here