# php $_POST method not working when trying to upload a file

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload

This is my first time trying to upload an image file to a directory using php . I fetch data from a mongodb database and print it as html .

```
foreach($storeCursor as $store){
                  echo "
                    <tr class = 'product-columns'>
                      <td class ='product__thumbnail store__thumbnail'>
                        <img src = ".$store["picture"]." class='cartItemImage' />
                        <form class = 'StoreImageForm' method = 'POST' action = '' 
                         enctype= 'multipart/form-data'>
                          <input type = 'file' name ='storeImg' class = 'storeImage' required/>
                          <br/>
                          <button type ='submit' name = 'submitImage' class = 'btn btn-sm btn-primary changeImageBtn' > Change Image </button>
                        </form>
                      </td>
                    </tr>";
       
  }
```

Now for each element I also print a form for the user to upload an image to my `../images/stores/` directory as shown above .

On my same page on top I have this php script to upload the file when submit button is clicked and my form is submitted :

```
<?php
 
 if(isset($_POST['submitImage'])) {
  echo "ENTERED"; //NOT SHOWN
  $target_dir = "../images/stores/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["storeImg"]["name"]);
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["storeImg"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["storeImg"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}

?>
```

My script never runs as it never enters the if statement and I have no idea why . "ENTERED" is not echoed on my page after submitting the image and no image is added to my directory

Everything happens on the same page as I submit my form and the page is refreshed .

What I tried : I  thought that maybe the problem was that I create the form as html when the data from mongodb is fetched so I also added a new form at the beginning of my page created with plain html and after submitting it I had the same result so that's not the problem I suppose .

I would appreciate your help .

NOTICE : If I do not refresh my page on action and move on another page my post method works ! But I still want it to work on my page on refresh . It seems that the issue is on refreshing on `action=''`

Comment: If you place an `echo` before the `if` condition, does that get printed?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes everything happens on the same page

Comment: Try dumping the entire `$_POST` at the top of the page.

Comment: Is your submit button named 'submit'?

Comment: @Ryah H Yeah ? Think that's it ? i changed it and have the same result

Comment: @El_Vanja  I put it on top of the page . Result is the same

Comment: Have you checked [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914979/php-post-not-working)?

Comment: @Martin just put the statement  if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])) and nothing happened

Comment: Why do you have a `,` after `action = '' `?

Comment: FYI: just tried the above code and it works. 'ENTERED' is displayed on the page

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I have deleted it . Forgot to remove it here sorry

Comment: You are certain that the second code block posted is as you say at the top of the same page?

Comment: @Andreas yes it is

Comment: Check my NOTICE :

Comment: You need to edit your question and actually show us the full relevant code on your page, in one single code block.

Comment: If it's particular to this page you may have a Controller issue or an Apache htaccess or similar silently changing how the data is sent to the page. Can you check these things?

Comment: try `print_r($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code its working. I have tested it

```
echo "
                <tr class = 'product-columns'>
                  <td class ='product__thumbnail store__thumbnail'>
                    <img src = '' class='cartItemImage' />
                    <form class = 'StoreImageForm' method = 'POST' action = '' 
                            enctype= 'multipart/form-data'>
             <input type = 'file' name ='storeImg' class = 'storeImage' 
                         required/>
                      <br/>
                      <button type ='submit' name = 'submitImage' class = 
         'btn btn-sm btn- primary changeImageBtn' > Change Image </button>
                    </form>
                  </td>
                </tr>";





if(isset($_POST['submitImage'])) {
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($_FILES);
     echo "</pre>";
  echo "ENTERED"; //NOT SHOWN
  $target_dir = dirname(__DIR__)."/uploaded/";   // Change this to your directory
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["storeImg"]["name"]);
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["storeImg"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["storeImg"]["name"])). " has 
been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
```

This is the output[image]

The only thing you need to change is the uploaded directory, fill in the image src attribute with the path you want to specify and dont forget to add in the action inside the form tag where you want to get the $_FILES Array thats it..:D

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using a new script which works perfectly

changeImage.php script

```
<?php
    
    if(isset($_POST["changeImage"]) ) {
      //add code to send file 
      //return to my page 
      header('Location: ../php/index.php#!/adminStores');
    }else{
      echo "no file sent";
    }

?>
```

and in my form : `action = 'changeImage.php'`