# php $_POST not working but $_GET is

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have and issue submitting my form. I've tried both with ajax and with a regular submit(`$.post()`, `$.get()`, `method="post"`, `method="get"`).

When I use either get I can get the data fine with `$_GET`, but using either post doesn't populate the `$_POST` variable.

Any suggestions would be great. I need to get post working, because I don't like the idea of using get for things like passwords.

**EDIT:**

POST:

`<form method="post" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
  <input type="text" name="some_input" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>`

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["some_input"])) echo $_POST["some_input"];
?>
```

Or

GET:

`<form method="get" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
  <input type="text" name="some_input" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>`

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["some_input"])) echo $_GET["some_input"];
?>
```

The first one doesn't show anything.

The second shows whatever I typed.

**EDIT 2:**

The following code work and populates my `$_POST`

```
<?php
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
print "</pre>";
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">

    <input type="text" name="name" value="ok" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

**Result:**

```
CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DATA:
string(21) "name=ok&submit=submit"
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "submit"
}
string(37) "/path/to/test-post.php"
```

The strange part is that `action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"` or no action at all works just fine, but either `action="test-post.php"` or `action="/path/to/test-post.php"` doesn't.

**Broken result:**

```
CONTENT_TYPE: 
DATA:
string(0) ""
array(0) {
}
string(37) "/path/to/test-post.php"
```

Comment: Show some of your actual code!

Comment: Paste your ajax and php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not too sure what was causing it in the first place, but I have discovered that if I am making a request with a relative path then I have to omit the file extension. e.g. `action="test-post"` instead of `action="test-post.php"`.

File extensions seem to be fine for `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` if I am sending it via get (`method="get"`), but not for `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` if I am sending it via post (`method="post"`).

***EDIT***

This was something to do with the `.htaccess` file. I don't know much about that file, so I don't know exactly which bit was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` see a simular issue:

[PHP $_POST not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002424/php-post-not-working)

Comment: Neither `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` would be populated if I used the `method="post"`

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to make a form with post, and handle it.
Notice you can leave the action blank (then it stays on the same URL).

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (isset($_POST["some_input"])) {
    echo $_POST["some_input"];
  }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="some_input" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried to query `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, but when I used post it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of submitting with POST threw AJAX :

HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="form">
<h3>Fill Your Information!</h3>
<div>
<label>Name :</label>
<input id="name" type="text">
<label>Email :</label>
<input id="email" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" type="password">
<label>Contact No :</label>
<input id="contact" type="text">
<input id="submit" onclick="myFunction()" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
      var emailVal = $('#email').val();
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "thePHPfile.php",
          data: 'data': emailVal ,         
          success: function(html) {
              alert(html);
          }
       });
    });
});
```

PHP :

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['data']){
          echo $_POST['data'];
        }
    ?>
```