# POST method is not passing the values, while GET method works fine

Tags: php, html, post, get

I am having some problems with the POST method for form submission in a localhost. I created a very simple page to test if both GET and POST methods work, but only the GET method is retrieving correctly the values. The code is as follows:

The form code:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

In the login.php page, I issue just a simple command to test if there is any value in the $_POST variable:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST);?>
```

which turns out to be an empty array.

However, if I change the method to GET, the command

```
<?php var_dump($_GET);?>
```

prints the following result:

```
array (size=2)
  'username' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'password' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

I have searched a lot of threads, but most of them were pointing coding errors, which does not seem to be the case here. In any case, if this information is useful, I am using WampServer 2.5 and PhpStorm 10.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best,
Lauro

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002424/php-post-not-working

Comment: Do you have `.htaccess` ? with redirects inside ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. You can check your login.php with a HTTP client(e.g. Postman) whether it is catching the post values or not. Moreover, for a test purpose try submitting the form in the same page. Then `var_dump` the `$_POST` variable. Besides you also should check `$_REQUEST` variable whether it is containing the value or not.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this a PHPStorm 10 issue ([see here](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5566345)). They'll probably fix it soon.

You can work around it by using `file_get_contents('php://input');`, or by reverting back to an earlier version of PHPStorm.

You might also be able set up a virtual machine with something like Vagrant and configure PHPStorm to use that. Looks like PHPStorm has an [integration with Vagrant](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/08/vagrant-support-in-phpstorm/) already.