# Php documenting array param

Tags: php, phpdoc

Question is about phpDocs, and describing array parameter.
For example i have code like this

```
<?= $view['form']->getElement('number_of_doors_id'); ?>
```

And phpStorm doesn't understand what 'form' key is.

I've tried

```
/**
* @var $view['form'] \\Framework\Templating\Helper\FormHelper
*/

/**
* @params $view['form'] \\Framework\Templating\Helper\FormHelper
*/
```

Comment: Have a look [\[ here \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703744/post-method-is-not-passing-the-values-while-get-method-works-fine). phpStorm is problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified @Robert answer and solved this problem like this

```
<?php
    /**
    * @var $view \Framework\Templating\Helper\FormHelper[]
    */
?>
```

And if you need two different types just do

```
/**
 * @var $view \Framework\Templating\Helper\FormHelper[]|\Framework\Templating\Helper\TranslatorHelper[]
 */
```

And so on

Comment: but it won't work because it says that very key in $view array is FormHelper type.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that comes to my mind is to use multiple type for array like this:

```
/**
* @var (\Framework\Templating\Helper\FormHelper|int)[] $view
*/
```

Where int is another type for array key

From [PHPDOC](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays):

> specified containing multiple types, the Type definition informs the
>   reader of the type of each array element. Each element can be of any
>   of the given types. Example: @return (int|string)[]

The other option is to assign this array variable to normal variable.

I think there is no other possibility so far.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation i ended up extracting the variables from the array and having individual `@var` blocks:

```
/**
* @var \Framework\Templating\Helper\FormHelper $form
* @var \Framework\Templating\Helper\UrlHelper $url
*/

extract($view);
$form->getElement('number_of_doors_id');
```

An alternative i have seen is having a 'viewModel' class per view:

```
class AboutViewModel
{
    /**
    * @var \Framework\Templating\Helper\FormHelper $form
    * @var \Framework\Templating\Helper\UrlHelper $url
    */
    public $form,
           $url;

}
```

and in your view

```
/**
* @var \Framework\Views\AboutViewModel $vm
*/
$vm->form->getElement('number_of_doors_id');
```

Comment: Good idea, sadly extract needs an array to work, and with **(array) $vew** isn't working good.

Comment: Oh, i thought `$view` was an array. What type is it? Some kind of collection?

Comment: Yeah, it's a symfony Templating component PhpEngine object.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating/introduction.html